# Whats wrong with the following unbind script?

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
(dolist (abcc '("C-a" "C-b"))
  (global-unset-key (kbd abcc)))
```

It keeps on giving the error :

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p abcc)
  read-kbd-macro(abcc)
  #[(keys) "\301!\207" [keys read-kbd-macro] 2 2180088](abcc)
  (kbd abcc)
  (global-unset-key (kbd abcc))
  (while --dolist-tail-- (setq abcc (car --dolist-tail--)) (global-unset-key (kbd abcc)) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--)))
  (let ((--dolist-tail-- ...) abcc) (while --dolist-tail-- (setq abcc ...) (global-unset-key ...) (setq --dolist-tail-- ...)))
  (dolist (abcc (quote ...)) (global-unset-key (kbd abcc)))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/name/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 63
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/name/.emacs" "/home/name/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[nil "\205\264
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I initially thought that this is a bug in Emacs.  I was very surprised nobody's come across this before.

Here is a workaround you can use:

```
(dolist (abcc '("C-a" "C-b"))
  (global-unset-key (read-kbd-macro abcc)))
```

What happens is kbd is a macro that wraps a function, however it doesn't evaluate its parameter explicitly.  So the symbol abcc is getting passed straight to the function.

After a bit more thinking (and reading the docs).  It's actually user error.

The doc-string for `kbd` clearly states that it should be used on string constants.

So `kbd` should be used when you only want a key's internal representation to appear in the compiled byte-code.  e.g.

```
(define-key foo-mode-map (kbd "C-a") 'foo)
```

But `read-kbd-macro` should be used when you want the argument to be evaluated.

Comment: These are the little things that make me hate Emacs (or more accurately, its API...). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`(keys)` is a macro that just passes right through to `(read-kbd-macro)`. The former also errors out for me for some reason, but the latter doesn't. Try that instead?

Answer (score 0):

`kbd` is a macro, so it does not evaluate its arg.